# After upgrade to Fedora 34, All the letters in system programs are replaced by their hexadecimal representations

Tags: fedora, fonts, gnome, bug

All the letters in system programs are replaced by their hexadecimal representations. I suppose that there some fonts are missed.
What I've tried is to change permissions for fonts and refresh font cache.Didn't work out
The problem itself[image]

Comment: That's definitely the "no font found for this character" boxes... Does `fc-match -s Sans` find any fonts?

Comment: @user1686 yes, It found about 20 fonts. The interesting thing is that in region and language settings i have all languages name rendered as boxes, but Chinese-like characters are rendered normal. May be this would be a tip.

Comment: update: on new user everything is OK

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here, in short reset default fonts and remove folders with old font. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/font-rendering-bug-all-characters-in-system-programs-are-rendered-as-hexadecimal-boxes/14306